# possible to re-add event listeners to datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a page with a datatable ("main") and another datatable ("info") that's hidden with "display:none". Some rows in "main" can open a child row, and the "info" datatable is then inserted into the child row. The way it's inserting the info row is by using removeChild on info's parent ("changesContainer") from the DOM and then inserting the outerHTML into the child row.

```
var source = document.getElementById('changesContainer')
var content = source.removeChild(source.firstElementChild)

target.innerHTML = content.outerHTML;
```

This kills all the event listeners on the search box, pagination, etc. Is there a way to re-initialize or re-add the event listeners to it, or another way to move it into the child row that will keep the event listeners?

Comment: `target.appendChild(content)`?

Comment: That did it, thank you!